# how to not display skipped hosts/tasks?

Tags: ansible

I have many playbooks and I don't have access the where Ansible is installed. I can write my playbooks locally on my laptop then I push them to a repo and I can run them via Jenkins. I can't control or change e.g. ansible.cfg or so. Is there a way to manipulate the ansible default stdout callback plugin per playbook without accessing the ansible host itself?

Comment: Very short answer: No. Meanwhile, you should be able to push your own ansible.cfg in your own project and the ansible plugin in jenkins should use it.

Comment: @Zeitounator +1. Ansible callback plugins can be configured in a configuration file or in the environment variables. [Jenkins Ansible playbook plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ansible/#plugin-content-playbook) is able to set neither the Ansible configuration file nor the environment variables for the playbook.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've tried to push my own ```ansible.cfg```  file as described  [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_CONFIG) (in the current directory - I assume the same directory where the playbook is) But nothing changed. I'm not sure if I had to change any configurations in Jenkins though and yes @VladimirBotka you are right with the Jenkins ansible-playbook plugin it is not possible to use either env. variable or config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is, you can use Environmental variable for this: check [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#display-skipped-hosts)

```bash
ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS=yes ansible-playbook main.yml
```

But for obvious [reasons](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/skippy_callback.html#deprecated) (It's deprecated) it's better to use the `ansible.cfg` option for this.

```ini
[defaults]
display_skipped_hosts = False
```

Comment: it is not possible to set env. variable (see comment above from @VladimirBotka) in Jenkins. However, I tried to use a "run shell" option before I invoke the playbook to set the env. variable but without luck. I guess I have to find a way to modify the default callback plugin.

Comment: If you check this [Using Jenkins Environment Variables](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ansible/#plugin-content-using-jenkins-environment-variables) you find that you can set the enviromental variables in the Jankins host.

Comment: Sorry but I can't follow, how should this help to solve my problem?

Comment: In POSIX Systems, you can do 2 things:

Either you prepend the command with the Environmental variable as I showed in the Answer or you can add in the Jenkins an Environment Variable and access like in the code from the linked resource.

But you have to be able to create env variables in the Jenkins Server.

Comment: Ok, I found the way now I just added another build step as ```Inject environment variables``` and put the ```ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS=False``` into ```Properties Content``` field it works now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @O.K., ANY parameter you set in Jenkins becomes an ENV-Var in your job - no need to inject anything - see [Jenkins : Define Parameters](https://wiki.jenkins.io/JENKINS/Define-Parameters.html)